# Error adding dll file into Setup Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-project

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to create a new Setup project.
I'm trying to add a file (dll) to the Application Folder,  there is nothing else in the project or in the solution.

[image]

But I get a way too generic error : `The operation could not be completed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it.
I was adding a DLL file created with VS2013 and .NET 4.5.
I tried to re-create the project with VS2008 and used the new dll and it worked.